# How do I nest my header object in the jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got a UL list and for reasons of CSS styling, I need to nest the object I wish to use as the header for my accordion inside a div within the LI.  Such that:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h4>Header</h4>
        </div>
        <p>This is my content</p>
    </li>
    ... other lis...
</ul>
```

Now, I'm wanting to hook up my accordion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').accordion({
        header: '' //What do I put here?
    });
});
```

When I set the header to h4, it doesn't work, when I use the div, it only works at the edge where the padding in the div reveals it from under the h4.  Is there a way of referencing the h4 within the div as the header?  I tried 'div>h4' but that doesn't work.  I'm sure this is quite simple but I haven't discovered how.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accordion works by finding your header selector matches then calling a `.next()` to get the content portion.  So for your markup, just use this:

```
$('ul').accordion({
    header: 'li>div' //.next() will get the <p>
});
```

I tested this, works fine here.

Comment: It seems to work okay if you're using the click event, but not if you're using the mouseover event.

Comment: @BenAlabaster - This is working here for me in Firefox, Chrome and IE, what browser are you seeing problems in?  `$('ul').accordion({ header: 'li>div', event: 'mouseover' });`